# How to check whether the object with duplicate LocalDateTime property already exist inside the ObservableArray?

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a method addAppointmentSaveButtonClicked that creates an object like this:

```
        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(appointmentId, chosenCustomerId, appointmentType, startDateTime, endDateTime, customerName);
```

Then it adds that object to observableArrayList like this:

```
        MainScreenController.appointmentDisplayList.add(newAppointment);
```

Now when I want to create a new Appointment or Edit existing one, I want to check whether there is already one with the same starting time in appointmentDisplayList array.

StartDateTime is LocalDateTime variable that is chosen from a ***combobox*** menu and always formatted like this:`2020-02-15 10:30:00` in ***30 minute intervals*** and there is no problems with milliseconds or anything like that.

**What I have done so far:**

I created following method that iterates through appointmentDisplayList like this:

```
    public static boolean existingAppointment(LocalDateTime ldt) {
    for (Appointment app : appointmentDisplayList) {
        if (app.getStart() == ldt) {
            System.out.println("True");
            return true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("False");
    return false;
}
```

Then whenever save button is clicked, I put in object creation code inside the ***IF code block*** like this:

```
if(!existingAppointment(startDateTime)) {
        AppointmentMethods.addAppointment(appointmentType, chosenCustomerId, utcStartTime, utcEndTime);
        appointmentId = AppointmentMethods.getAppointment(chosenCustomerId, utcStartTime).getAppointmentId();

        Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(appointmentId, chosenCustomerId, appointmentType, startDateTime, endDateTime, customerName);
        MainScreenController.appointmentDisplayList.add(newAppointment);}
```

Now the problem I am having with my code is that every single time and date I choose for my new appointent, this if block always comes as false, and duplicate appointments are added to my ArrayList.

I hope any experienced coder can help me figure out what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried app.getStart().equals(ldt)?

Comment: Can you post it as answer so I can marked it as answered. It is still so hard to wrap my head around why it works the way you suggested! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects, `==` tests if they are the same object. Assuming it has been set up well, `.equals()` tests if they have the same value. For a good discussion of setting up .equals, see [nice overview of overriding equals, including visualization of this issue](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/apcsareview/OOBasics/ooOverrideInherited.html)

That is why you needed `app.getStart().equals(ldt)` to compare the date values, to see if both objects represented the same date. `app.getStart() == ldt` was checking if they were the same object, which is not what you wanted.